# Does most of the formatting remain intact when a standard thesis PDF is converted to Word?

Tags: pdf, conversion, msword, acrobat, adobe

Overall formatting of the PDF document which was built from LaTeX and then later converted to MS Word.

Comment: I am very sure that it will be a big *mess*.

Comment: I don't know how you plan to convert PDF to Word but however you do it, I agree with the previous comment. It will be a mess, I would imagine. You might have slightly better luck converting the LaTeX source to Word but be prepared to do an awful lot of manual reformatting post-conversion.

Comment: @cfr- I have adobe acrobat pro to convert pdf to word. Can you tell how to convert latex source to word?

Comment: This is a duplicate of other questions about  conversions to Word, there is no standard conversion method but most will lose some or all of the formatting or text or mathematics.

Comment: I depends on the conversion path and software utilities you have, how complicated your document is, and if you are going to edit the documents afterwards. [The free Nitro PDFtoWord](https://www.pdftoword.com/) does a good job, but the  Word document will be a mess if you start editing it. The expensive Adobe Pro will convert a little better, but it will still be a mess after you start editing.

Comment: @HarishKumar I can confirm that. I converted my company's [Annual Report 2013](http://hugin.info/155892/R/1773339/604287.pdf) this morning using Adobe Pro, and started the editing. It was a mess on all pages with graphs, pictures and tables.